# why will two bodies rotate about their centre of mass if they do so for their mutual attraction

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

If two bodies rotated because of their mutual attraction. They will do so about their centre of mass. Why is that ?
I understand that if there is no external force then the centre of mass must not be accelerated. But if i apply a constant external force. On the two bodies, they still rotate about their centre of mass. Why is that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gravitational force acting on two particles](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203494/)

Comment: Do you mean rotate or orbit?

Comment: I mean orbit. Sorry for my language. They orbit around their centre of mass.

Answer (score 0):

Fictitious forces might help you here. Consider two scenarios:

1: Two bodies interacting via mutual attraction, no external force, center of mass not accelerating.

2: Two bodies interacting via mutual attraction and a constant external force $F$, center of mass accelerating at $a = \frac{F}{m}$.

Although these two scenarios seem different, we can transform scenario 2 to a different frame, namely the center of mass frame. In the center of mass frame, there is a translational fictitious force that cancels $F$, and therefore the two bodies are only interacting via mutual attraction and center of mass is obviously no longer accelerating. So scenario 1 and 2 are two representations of the same physics in different frames.

Notice that this argument would not work in any other frame because $$F_{ext} \neq ma_{p}$$ where $p$ is an arbitrary point on the two bodies that is not their center of mass.

Comment: Thank u very much for your reply. But can u kindly explain the your last equation. Why is that. I don't understand. Sorry

Comment: No problem. So, $F_{ext} = ma_{CM}$ always holds, for any extended body. However, if different parts of the body are moving relative to the center of mass, then obviously $a_{CM} \neq a_{elsewhere}$. The equation I gave you follows from this argument.